# What is the "desktop couch scratch" folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one, firefox, couchdb

What is the "desktop couch scratch" folder, and what do I do with it, if anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is used by the bindwood extension during synchronization. If you're using bindwood and delete it, it will get recreated the next time you sync; I'm not sure what would happen if you delete it *during a sync*, so don't do that :)

If you're not using bindwood you can safely delete it.